# The method setContent(byte) in the type Document is not applicable for the arguments (byte[])

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

[image: This is the image of my error]

I'm getting the error while uploading the file in the database with spring boot.

Comment: Please post the relevant code and your error as text

Comment: it is solved. I mistaken, I did not specify byte as an array.